# Alternating colours of lists in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have a list in jQuery mobile that has one colour for an odd number member of the list and a different colour for even numbers within the same list. For example within the list the first list item will be grey and for the other item the list colour will be white. Can this be done with jQuery Mobile.

I should also mention that this list will be built with an ajax response.

Comment: Tried anything? Easy to do with CSS3. `li:nth-child(even) {background: red;}`

Comment: no didn't try anything at this point its just a question in my head at the moment

Comment: Easy way, as @NADH said. JS way, to loop inside list view items and change background based on their index number, odd or even.

Comment: If you loaded the entries with AJAX you may need to use `$("#listresults").listview('refresh');` to append the CSS of the chosen style.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div data-demo-html="true">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li data-theme="a">Acura</li>
                <li data-theme="b">Audi</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/demo-html -->
```

Alternating the data-theme attribute should do the trick.

Comment: Added a new part to the question which is if this is being built using ajax how can this be done? I wont be able to add the theme for each response appended to the list

Comment: There is a javascript API method to do what you want I believe its just a simple css class actually. Look at the API documentation. I also can't understand why you cant just build the ajax response this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have tried anything. But I have made the function simple for you. Just use ajax in place of loop, rest all will be same

```
var swatch = ['a', 'b'];
$list = $("#list");

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $list.append("<li data-theme='" + swatch[i % 2] + "'>List Item</li>");
}
$list.listview('refresh');
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/ahWzh/

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, add these two lines:

```
ul.ui-listview li:nth-child(even) a { background-color: #ffd800; }
ul.ui-listview li:nth-child(odd) a { background-color: #000; }
```